# Tricky differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\begin{aligned}f(x) = 1 - \left ( \frac{u-x}{u-l} \right )^{B}\end{aligned}$$

After differentiating, the answer is:

$$\begin{aligned}f'(x) = \left ( \frac{B}{u-l} \right )\left ( \frac{u-x}{u-l} \right )^{B-1}\end{aligned}$$

What strategy should be used to do that differentiation from $f(x)$ to get $f'(x)$?

Comment: Is your $u$ actually an $x$? (use $(f\circ g)^\prime = g^\prime f^\prime\circ g$, and the known derivative of $x\mapsto x^B$.

Comment: u is just some upper bound parameter, l lower bound @ClementC.

Comment: As written, your function $F$ is a constant: it does not depend on $x$, which is its variable.

Comment: Typo my bad.  Fixed equations. @ClementC.

Comment: OK. See my first comment to compute the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use $(g \circ f)'(x) = g'(f(x))f'(x)$

$$f(x) = 1 -\Big(\frac{u-x}{u-l}\Big)^{B} \Rightarrow f'(x) = -B\Big(\frac{u-x}{u-l}\Big)^{B-1} \Big(\frac{-1}{u-l}\Big)$$